# Templates for HTML/Javascript/CSS - Progress tracking

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

Where can I find templates for html/javascript/css (something that uses notepad as an editor haha) please? I was hoping to find a template that displays some text or picture upon clicking such as follows:

[image]

Pardon dumb question. It's been 8 years since I've done this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use notepad as editor :D

here are some links for easy templates:
[Free Templates](http://all-free-download.com/free-website-templates/simple-templates-html-and-css.html)

Without Pictures just some samples to put your code in ///
os-templates.com/free-basic-html5-templates

Here is also a very good website to directly put your code in and to get you result.

[Learning HTML CSS again](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp)

Also you can find everything on this website for getting again started with HTMl and CSS also Javascript

Try on [W3C] easy examples to understand the image input again. w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Sorry I don't have 10 reputations to put more links in....

Comment: Thanks for the links, JCD! I tried a different thing though. Got a lot of rep now? ^-^

Comment: BCLC I got the rep now :) Thanks ^-^